# Deduce weak_ptr argument from shared_ptr

Tags: c++, shared-ptr, weak-ptr

The following gives me compiler error:

> could not deduce template argument for 'const std::weak_ptr<_Ty> &'
>   from 'std::shared_ptr'

```
#include <memory>

class Foo
{
public:

    template<typename R>
    void Bar(std::weak_ptr<R> const & p)
    {
        p;
    }
};

int main(void)
{
    auto foo = Foo();
    auto integer = std::make_shared<int>();

    foo.Bar(integer);
}
```

I tried,

```
template<typename R>
void Bar(std::weak_ptr<R::element_type> const & p)
{

}
```

, which seems syntatically incorrect.  The following works but I wondered if it's possible to get the conversion in p, without creating another temporary?

```
template<typename R>
void Bar(R const & p)
{
    auto w = std::weak_ptr<R::element_type>(p);
}
```

To be clear I'd like to explicitly state the function should take a shared or weak_ptr, so I don't like the R const & p solution.

For completeness this also works of course:

```
template<typename R>
void Bar(std::shared_ptr<R> const & p)
{
    auto w = std::weak_ptr<R>(p);
}
```

Comment: element_type is the type of shared_ptr (trait).  <R> in this instance is a shared_ptr<R:element_type>.  At least that seems to be what the type deduction process is telling  me.  So in the example element_type will be "int".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The template parameter `R` of `std::weak<R>` cannot be deduced from an instance of `std::shared_ptr<A>` because the converting constructor (which takes `std::shared_ptr<Y>`) is a constructor-template which means`Y` could be anything — and there is no way to deduce `R` from `Y` (which is deduced to be `A`). Have a look at the converting constructor.

You could write this:

```
template<typename T>
auto make_weak(std::shared_ptr<T> s) ->  std::weak_ptr<T>
{
  return { s };
}
```

Then call it as:

```
foo.Bar( make_weak(integer) );
```

Answer (score 2):

With C++ 17's [class template deduction](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template_deduction), this now should be legal:

```
auto shared = std::make_shared< int >( 3 );
auto weak = std::weak_ptr( shared );
std::weak_ptr weak2( shared );
```

See it on [coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a391c1841d4709f7).

Comment: And just FYI, this [only got fixed in clang's `libcxx` in May 2020](https://reviews.llvm.org/D69603).

Answer (score 1):

Because you are smarter than the compiler, you must help it deduce that type.

Observe this part of your code.

```
template<typename R>
void Bar(std::weak_ptr<R> const & p)
```

**You** know that for every possible `R` that could exist, there is **exactly one `R`** for which there is an implicit conversion from `std::shared_ptr<int>`.  You likely didn't write any conversion operators elsewhere that would apply here.

Your C++ compiler won't know or assume this.  So you should call the function as:

```
foo.Bar( std::weak_ptr<int>{integer} );
```

Or try the approach in Mark B's answer.

Answer (score 1):

You need to handle two (language-wise) totally unrelated types, so you need to provide two overloads, one one for each pointer type. The shared_ptr version can then call through to the weak_ptr version by providing the correct `T` in its invocation.